# create a css format with socil media icon

Tags: html, css

[image]

i have this design which i wish to implement in html and css. i have done the background part, social media buttons, and also written the stay connected text. the thing which i am not able to get is how to make the lines around the text.
I have tried `<hr>` tag but that is placing the line and text in different lines i.e it takes 3 lines. can anyone tell how i can create this image in css

at present my code is:

```html
<footer style="background-color:black; height:100px; margin-bottom:0px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <center>
        <div class="row">
          <p>Stay Connected</p>
          <ul class="social-icons icon-circle icon-rotate list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Answer -> http://jsfiddle.net/p8jdzqvL/embedded/result/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p8jdzqvL/

Comment: @Dhru'soni thanks it worked, but can u plz tell me how i can place some space between line and text

Comment: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stay Connected &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; hahah do it it's to simple :) http://jsfiddle.net/p8jdzqvL/1/embedded/result/